# Getting the coordinate within a rotated element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

I have a question that is math and also JavaScript related. I'm trying to come up with a function to get me the true coordinate within an element that was clicked.  The difficulty here is that the element could be **rotated**.

Otherwise, we could easily get the coordinate within the element on a click by doing using jQuery:

```
const ELEMENT_X = event.pageX - object.offset().left;
const ELEMENT_Y = event.pageY - object.offset().top;
```

[image]
Not too sure if these JavaScript objects can help calculate the true coordinate of the element:

```
DOMPoint
DOMMatrix
```

We know the coordinate of the click on the viewport, the width and height of the element, its offset left/top and we know the rotation angle (could be negative or positive [-180, 180]). So the function I'm trying to get to return the true coordinate of of any four-sided shape would look something like this:

```
function getClickedCoordinateOfElement(event, elementDOM, rotationAngleInDegrees) {
    let coordinate[];
    let x, y;

    ...

    return(coordinate[x, y]);
}
```

I think the solution requires some manipulation of the Sin or Cos of a triangle, but I'm not too sure.

I forgot to mention that the element is not anchored to the origin and could be anywhere.

How would we get the coordinate of the green dot in relative to the inside of the element?  The top left corner (ax) of the element would be (0, 0).

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far that didn't work.

Comment: It is worth to show a picture to make things more clear